# Remote video from Safari iPhone showing black-screen

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I moved from zoom to twilio with one of my client's video conferencing project. I followed tutorials and docs to show 1 to 1 video between two participants. I developed it as web app with JS scripts in PHP.

So far, it is working from desktop to desktop and from android chrome to desktop. But from iPhone safari to Chrome Desktop, its showing black screen. On mobile, it loads video of both local and remote, but on desktop, its showing remote user's video as black screen. I tried everything, also searched through documentations and forums, but couldn't found related issue. I was wondering, if you could help here.

I'm using safari on iPhone 13.4 and latest Chrome in mac Desktop.
Here's screenshot of how it shows.
[remote screen black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk5Hq.png)
P.S. the developer console in the screenshot, on the right, is from Mobile safari.

LMK, if need to share the codes.

Comment: Did you happen to find any fix? Im experiencing the same issues

Comment: @DrSmrtnik Yes, it worked for me later on. I worked for this project a long ago now, so couldn't really remember how it was fixed. I can share codes, if it helps you!

Comment: That would be great, since i still can't figure out what the issue is

Comment: Here it is: 
[gist: TwilioConnect](https://gist.github.com/mit2sumit/456a4a311830e0473b3a87728d38bb12)
Hope it helps 